# How to log requests to mex endpoints

Tags: wcf

I've got a WCF service with exposed mex endpoints in it. I need to implement additional loging for it

```
        <endpoint address="MEX"
              binding="mexHttpBinding"
              contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

Is there any way to log users request for mex endpoints?